# configure Dokku (Procfile) to use specific Docker image

Tags: ubuntu, flask, docker, dokku

I'm working on automatic deploy system. I have a specific image tagged `base_image` where all necessary requirements installed.

Every app is on Python Flask. I've tried to add `Dockerfile` to my app-root before pushing to dokku with the following content:

`FROM base_image`

The deploy fails without error-message - I guess that I've overwritten default Python/Flask config.

How can I use Dokku `Procfile` to specify image? Or shall I fix `Dockerfile` ?

---

P.S - my Docker `base_image` is fine - I've checked manually from shell that all necessary requirements are installed there.

I need this image because I don't want install the same things every time - I just want to link them and create own environment (image) for every app